# Grafana dashboard blank after import

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I deployed grafana and Prometheus pods on a test kubernetes cluster . /var/lib/grafana is mounted on shared directory on another server. On importing grafana dashboard  , I get a blank screen. Nothing happens. Is it due to the shared mount ? Can anyone provide some inputs to resolve this. I have noticed , it works fine when /var/lib/grafana is not mounted.

Tested with and without volume mount. The problem is only with volume mount on external shared directory.

It should display the imported dashboard.